# ADF and KPSS test both rejected

Tags: unit-root, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test

When testing the stationarity of residuals after OLS estimation, the ADF and KPSS test have opposing conclusions when it comes to rejecting the null:

- ADF: Rejection of null concludes evidence of stationarity
- KPSS: Rejection of null concludes evidence of non-stationarity.

In addition, the sample size is fairly low (approx 40 observations). Is this what's throwing off the test? From what I've read ADF has low power as well. In such a situation would it be appropriate to use DF-GLS instead?

Comment: It depends on many things. Are you using trend? constant? What about the other tests? (there are many more)

Comment: Note that when KPSS rejects the null of stationarity it does not necessarily suggest presence of a unit root. It could be another type of nonstationarity.

Comment: @luchanacho, this is the conclusion on all cases, i.e. no constand or trend, constant, constant and trend

Comment: @RichardHardy I'm not familiar with other forms of nonstationarity. Do you have a resource I could check out on this?

Comment: Some times series textbook, e.g. Zivot "Modeling Financial Time Series with S-PLUS" (2006) or the original paper by the four authors (KPSS are their surnames' first letters).

Comment: this reference is maybe interesting when it comes to looking at ADF and KPSS simultaneously: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176598001499